# Как получить доступ к redux-стору внутри thunk

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

Возникла проблема обращения к `api` при использовании `redux-thunk`. Вот так выглядит создании стора.

```
const middlewares = [thunk.withExtraArgument(new Api('/api'))];

export default (initialState = {}) => {
  const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));

  return { store };
};
```

Класс `Api` выглядит так:

```
class Api {
  constructor(baseUrl, accessToken = null) {
    this.request = axios.create({
      baseURL: baseUrl,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    });
  }

  signIn(credentials) {
    return this.request.post('sessions', credentials);
  }

  ...

  fetchNews(filters) {
    return this.request.get('news', filters); 
  }
}
```

Экшен для доступа получения всех новостей выглядит так:

```
export const fetchNews = (filters) => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  const { data } = await api.fetchNews(filters);

  console.log(data);
};
```

Вопрос в том как внутри класса `Api` получить доступ к redux стору для получения токена?

Answer (score 0):

Приветствую! Ну так прямо из экшн креатора и передайте? Можно конечно использоваться синглтон паттерн для стора, но это было бы  усложнением

```
  export const fetchNews = (filters) => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
      const { data } = await api.fetchNews(filters, getState().user.token);
    };
```

Comment: Я думал об этом, но каждый раз когда мне будет требоваться обращение к api будет необходимо передавать токен, что не удобно. Есть ли какие то другие способы?

Comment: согласен, поэтому почему бы не хранить токен в localStorage

Comment: Токен храниться в редьюсере user и при помощи `redux-persist` сохраняется в localStorage. Конечно токен можно вытащить из localStorage внутри класса `Api` но мне кажется что идиоматически правильно рассматривать стор как единственный источник данных поэтому предполагалось брать токен из стейта.

Comment: а что за токен такой? токены долго не живут обычно, поэтому непонятно зачем его сохранять долговременно в сторе. во всех статьях по jwt что я читал рекомендуется хранить токен или в кукис или в локалСторадж. а так.. ну можно передать в констуктор api ссылку на ваш стор в крайнем случае

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=where+to+keep+jwt+token&oq=where+to+keep+jwt+token&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.4939j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: вот хотелось бы узнать как можно прокинуть ссылку на стор в конструктор api

Comment: просто можете импортировать его из того файла, где стор создаётся. если он создаётся в индексном файле, то можно это дело перенести в нечно вроде store.js, а оттуда уже испортировать